# Does eating birds' nests stimulate the regeneration of cells?

Tags: nutrition

Edible bird's nests are believed to have high nutritional and medicinal value. This is why [it can cost up to $4500 per pound](http://www.livescience.com/21534-edible-birds-nests-health.html).

There are many vague claims about the benefits of eating birds' nests. For example, Singapore's [EZHealth magazine](http://www.livescience.com/21534-edible-birds-nests-health.html) claims:

> As it is rich in protein, collagen and other nutrients and minerals, the consumption of bird’s nest is scientifically proven to have several health benefits, such as **stimulating the regeneration of cells**, strengthening our immune and respiratory system, and improving the performance of our internal organs.

I wonder whether it is really beneficial to consume bird's nest, given that it is only made from the saliva of cave-dwelling birds called swiftlets.

So, is there any scientific evidence that demonstrates that birds' nests stimulate the regeneration of cells?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "beneficial?

Comment: I started looking at the scientific literature on this but the problem is that there's a lot of it, and the review articles are sometimes in predatory open access journals...

Comment: @Sklivvz , see the last paragraph of my question . I think it clarifies enough

Comment: @Graviton: I am afraid it doesn't. We need some specific claim we can investigate.

Comment: See this for more info: http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/2508/should-we-accept-is-this-food-healthy-questions

Comment: @Oddthinking, I've listed some of the beneficial claims of bird nest. Can we now reopen this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These claims are all pseudo-scientific. There is no good evidence of the birds' nests having medical value. (It is not even clear that the claim of "stimulating the regeneration of cells" is necessarily a beneficial thing.)

A paper reviewing the evidence was written in 2012, *[Sketch of the edible bird's nest and its important bioactivities](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0963996912001895). Despite the authors being very optimistic about the (undemonstrated) potential benefits of the food, they were forced to conclude:

> its bioactivities and medicinal value are still open to
>   question as there are not much scientific research on the medicinal
>   properties. Not many components contributing to the biological functions
>   of edible bird's nest have been isolated and purified from the
>   nest so far. This reason along with the nests' high price makes the
>   procedure of investigating the bioactivity of the edible bird's nest
>   more difficult. As there is a mess in the use of classification methods
>   of edible bird's nests at present, it's important for future researchers
>   to make clear what species their nests belong to. More proteome
>   and genome studies should be carried out to thoroughly investigate
>   edible bird's nest. More scientific work should be done to elucidate
>   the biological and medicinal functions of the nest.

In short, there is no reason to believe birds' nests treat any illnesses *and* the proponents aren't even clear which species of birds should be used for their nests. Chinese Traditional Medicine is a [pseudo-science](http://www.skepticblog.org/2008/11/02/tcm-1/).